# How to identify newer or changed files from TFS command line?

Tags: android-studio, tfs

The development environment I am using (Android Studio) does not support TFS. The only tool that is available to me is TFS command line.

When I modify a source file from within Android Studio, it removes the read-only attribute on the file and saves it. Eventually I end up with a directory that contains a) files that have been modified and b) newer files.

I am trying to understand how to identify these modified/newer files.

Commands `tf folderdiff . /r` shows me newer/changed files but ignores `.tfignore` directives. As a result, I end up browsing through 100s of intermediate files.

Is there a better way to get the list of newer/changed files that honors the directives in `.tfignore` file? Regards.

Comment: TFS is fully supported by Android Studio if you create a Team Project with Git as the repository type...

Answer (score 4):

I'm slightly confused - .tfignore is created by TFS after all, so it should be used by TFS submit window. However, the fact that you say that files are read-only tells me that your workspace is "server workspace" which does not use .tfignore.
Try creating "local workspace" that respects .tfignore and which files are ReadWrite.